# Flow.js and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to use Flow with React and.
I am getting these two errors:

1. error:
   import '../../assets/css/clientStyle.css';  => Required module not found
2. error
   Property `sortByLastChangedDate` is incompatible:
    15: const TableComponent = (props: Props) => {
                                       ^^^^^ property `sortByLastChangedDate`. Property not found in. See: src/components/client/TableComponent.js:15

.

```
import '../../assets/css/clientStyle.css';

type Props = { /* ... */ };

type State = {
  showClients: boolean,
  data: any[],
  lastCreated: any[],
};
@observer
export default class Client extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showClients: false,
      data: [],
      lastCreated: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TableComponent
            data={this.state.data}
            isHeaderWithIcons="true"
            title="some title"
            sortByCreationDate={this.sortByCreationDate}
            sortByLastChangedDate={this.sortByLastChangedDate}
          />
    )
  }


}

// TableComponent

type Props = {
  data: any[],
  title: any,
  isHeaderWithIcons: string,
  sortByCreationDate: () => mixed,
  sortByLastChangedDate: () => mixed,
}
const TableComponent = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className="clients-container">
      <h3>{props.title}</h3>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the import error, you'll want to modify your `.flowconfig` file as described [in the docs for name mapper](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-extension-string-string)

Your other error is problematic because you're passing an undefined function through. `this.sortByLastChangedDate` is not defined on `Client`. You may have meant `this.props.sortByLastChangedDate` (I can't know for sure since you didn't include the props for `Client` above).